# react highcharts randomly rendered or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I cannot figure the problem that the highcharts randomly rendered; I use highcharts version 7.2.0 and In backend data(Springboot) supplied with no error when I found in logger.debug().

I also cannot catch any error in console.log() or etc.

```
highcharts.chart('className-${data.chartType}-${idx}', {...})
```

Here's the code, (not at work, so I wrote what I remember) The id of the  element does not overlap with other charts. I can supply the description of the code tomorrow.

The chart randomly appears when I restart the page, even if I delete the caches.

Is it the highcharts version issue or I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the official React wrap: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

Here is a sample demo showing how to use wrap to create a chart: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-dor1s